# Cant load any page with struts 2 . Issue with web.xml

Tags: struts2

I am trying to run [this](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/object-backed-java-beans-example-1.html) example using struts 2. I inserted the libraries in the Lib folder of Web-Inf of a dynamic web project in eclipse.

My Web.xml looks like this now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and i created the struts.xml and placed it inside the source folder , the content of which is

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="UserAction" class="struts.UserAction">
            <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/result.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

So now when i run any jsp i get the following error in eclipse console

> > Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/D:/Users/Don/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Mscs674-Struts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.4.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162

and this on the webpage

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: When you tell people what directories you're putting things in, it's *really* important to be very accurate with regards to capitalization etc. For example, right now, the directories you list are incorrect--libraries should go in `WEB-INF/lib`, with that capitalization.

Comment: Also, that is a very old version of S2 and should *not* be used. The libraries @Fidrizers lists are more current (but still old), and will likely not work with the older version of S2. Also, that you're seeing an issue relating to the GXP plugin means you're including libraries you're *not* using, which you should *not* do--plugins can alter the default behavior of S2. Turn `devMode` on and check your logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems  like some jars are missing .. !!

The common dependecies are ::

```
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
- commons-io-1.3.2.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
- freemarker-2.3.15,jar
- log4j-1.2.14.jar
- ognl-2.7.3.jar
- xwork-core-2.1.6.jar
```

Check  the version number and add jars to classpath.

Comment: I added these files to the lib folder under WEB-INF and then I right clicked on the folder in the libraries tab selected "ADD JAR" and then browsed to the same project and selected all the libraries that I posted.

Comment: All the rar files are there except log4j

Comment: How you build this project??

Go to eclipse --> new--> Create new  Dynamic web project --> Server(tomcat or jboss whichever u have) and 2.5 module web version. Give project name --> and Complete it --> Copy paste everythin from this zip and paste it in web-inf folder and copy the java classes in src folder. and run it --> it will work fine . Issue is  that your web.xml is not building properly.

Comment: Initially i just copied all the jar files from the struts2.3.4 framework that i downloaded. Now i deleted them from the library and only copied the above files and am getting this : SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: looks like issue is not with jar. Try to do as pointed in comments by me

Answer (score 2):

The best way i found to create struts 2 application is to use the struts-blank.jar file. It has all the required configurations done for you, and you can remove some example files. It will have all the jars and xml files created for you.
If you still have problems, try doing this now...

Answer (score 2):

first remove all jar (adding all lib is not solution)

Only add necessary libraries

so problem is you are having too many lib

Answer (score 1):

You do One thing..add **javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar** file.it will remove your error like

```
Dispatcher initialization failed java.lang.RuntimeException:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ..
```

I hope this will help you..

Comment: It comes with the distribution 2.3.4.1.