# Eclipse detects no errors but can't find bean when running tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, struts2, javabeans

Eclipse does not detect any errors in the code but when I run it through Tomcat, it won't render in the browser because it cannot locate the resource. The console says

```
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/Users/jasonrodriguez/Java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/wtpwebapps/TutorialFinder/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.15.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
```

but my library path is connected to `lib` like it is supposed to and I have the whole library of jars. Am I missing something?

**Here is my action class :**

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.action;

import org.koushik.javabrains.service.TutorialFinderService;

public class TutorialAction {
    public String execute() {
        TutorialFinderService tutorialFinderService = new TutorialFinderService();
        String bestTutorialSite = tutorialFinderService.getBestTutorialSite();
        System.out.println(bestTutorialSite);
        return "success";
    }

}
```

**`struts.xml` :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" namespace="/tutorials" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getTutorial" class="org.koushik.javabrains.action.TutorialAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**`web.xml:`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TutorialFinder</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
      <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>
      
      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Here is a screenshot of my file hierarchy :**

[image]

**Here are my jars :**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you use all these Struts2 plugins? At least you have class clash as you using two different version of Tiles - 2.0 and 3.0 - which isn't allowed. Remove all unused plugins (e.g. struts2-gxp-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies are used only at compile time. To include library (like struts) you must configure "Deployment Assembly" in project's properties. [Here](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/1.5/newandnoteworthy/j2ee.html) you can find a description of the feature.

Comment: My Deployment Assembly was already included and configured from the start but when I ran Tomcat, it said it could not load the configuration. So, now that is why I am confused. Do you know what the problem could be? There are no visible errors in Eclipse

Comment: Can you export project as war file and attach the content of WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: Sure thing. I don't think Stack allows attachments though. I can post images but pretty sure they don't like attachments. I can send you a private email with an attachment though.

Comment: It's enough the image or the file names.

Comment: Seems you have the same problem described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986375/cant-load-any-page-with-struts-2-issue-with-web-xml

Comment: I added images of my jars. At first, I only had the jars I needed loaded but since my program wasn't working, I thought I might be missing a jar or something so I just installed them all. I looked at that other post but it looks like he was missing some dependencies. I am pretty sure I have all dependencies included. Do you see any missing? It looks like I have what I need there but the console tells me it cant load file configuartion

Comment: You nave a lot of jar :-),but I don't see log4j.

Comment: I literally installed all the jars in the struts lib folder. Are you sure the log4j jar would prevent my program from running? It doesn't seem to come with Struts by default. I googled it and it seems to just be a logging tool

Comment: What do you mean by "your dependencies are used only at compile time"? The default "compile" scope *does* include the library in the assembly (e.g., runtime classpath). If OP is using a Maven plugin this shouldn't need to be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have created a Eclipse library that point to the `lib` folder of the Struts2 distro and added it to classpath (or build path whatever they call it).

It's not bad if you want your project to be compiled, it has to resolve dependencies to the configured libraries. But the problem is along with compile time dependencies you have added a runtime dependencies that are all deployed to the application server when you run your application. It's not good.

As far as I remember a newer versions of Eclipse has something called "web deployment assembly" and it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969605/deployment-assembly-in-eclipse). Combined with maven you can get better control applying scopes to this feature.